# How do i get multiple rows with max value of a column using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list `List<Class>list11` where `Class` contains `Num1` as one of the parameter.
There are multiple rows in list1 with same num1 and some duplicated as well. How can I get distinct rows with Max(num1) using LINQ ?

Comment: Best way is to use GroupBy Num1 and then take first item.  Something like this : var results = list11.GroupBy(x => x.Num1).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();  A GroupBy produces a two dimensional object <key, List<obj>>  You want to take first item from each key.

Comment: @jdweng - I'd suggest using `.SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))` over `.Select(x => x.First())` as it is more "refactorable" and is more resilient to filtering prior to the select.

Comment: @Enigmativity : OP wants one of each Num1 and your code does not do this.

Comment: @jdweng - My code is identical in function to yours.

Comment: @Enigmativity : Where is the GroupBy?  It wasn't clear when I first looked at your response that you were implying the GroupBy.  Does your code compile?  I had a compiler error recently when using SelectMany and inside wasn't an array.  I do not think you can use SelectMany with a singleton.

Comment: @jdweng - Please read my comment again. All I said was replace the `.Select(x => x.First())` with `.SelectMany(x => x.Take(1))` in your query.

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your comments. I tried all of the options but none of them work for me. :(